# Angular 4 Getting Child route param

Tags: angular, angular-routing

In my application the route is something like this :-

```
{ path: 'route-a', component: ComponentA, children : [

    { path: ':param-b', component: ChildComponentB, children : [

        { path: ':param-c', component: ChildComponentC }

    ]}

]},
```

Now in my `ComponentA` I am trying to subscribe to child param to get `param-b`

```
     this.routefirstChild$ = this.route.firstChild.params.subscribe($routefirstChild => {

        console.log($routefirstChild, '$routefirstChild');

     });
```

Now when I navigate to `example.com/route-a` I am getting `this.route.firstChild is null` error.

But if I navigate to `example.com/route-a/1234` the param is passed. Which observable to have to subscribe that doesn't trigger an error but would pass the child params when the route is activated.

Comment: Hm... actually you are getting what u wrote, first navigation seems have no child parameters, I see no problem here, all runs according code 'example.com/route-a' are path to componentA, and there are no child routes activated at all

Comment: I agree, but eventually there will be child routes, how do I ensure if there is a child route that gets activated the parent gets notified about the child param?

Comment: You are doing it right now, when u added 1234 as params it is componentB parameters, and you sad that you are notified ;)

Comment: Only if I reload the page not when clicked via routerLink. Because the subscription has failed in the first instance when there are no child, I don't get notified once there are.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up implementing the following solution :-

`import { ActivatedRoute, NavigationEnd, Router } from '@angular/router';`

```
     this.routeEvents$ = this.router.events.subscribe(

     ( $routeEvents ) : void => {

        if ( $routeEvents instanceof NavigationEnd ) {

            if(typeof this.route.firstChild != "undefined" && this.route.firstChild){

                console.log(this.route.firstChild.snapshot.params, 'this.route.firstChild.snapshot.params');

            }

        }

     });
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
function getChildMostRoute(route: ActivatedRoute) {
    let route = route.snapshot;

    // Get the current active descendent
    while (route.firstChild) {
        route = route.firstChild;
    }

    const allPathsJoined = route.pathFromRoot
        .map(s => s.url.map(u => u.path).join('/'))
        .join('/')

    return {
        path: allPathsJoined,
        params: route.queryParams,
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Angular 9**

```
this.activatedRoute.firstChild.paramMap.pipe(tap()).subscribe(params => {
      const id = params.get('id');
});
```

ActivatedRoute holds the current route (partial) only. Which means, if you are at /xyz then your ActivatedRoute will hold /xyz/:id if there is a parameter.  If you are currently in a parent route and you'd like to access a parameter in the child route, you can call as above, or if you would like to use a grand child route parameter, you can use `activatedRoute.firstChild.firstChild` to react there and then subscribe to paramMap as shown above. Similarly, you can also go up in the routing hierarchy using activatedRoute.parent instead of firstChild.

Hope this helps!